# C++ Eigen reductions are slower than simple loop

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

Given two 3xK matrices I wish to compute the squared average of column by column dot products.
This can be accomplished with a simple loop:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic> L(3,K);
Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic> P(3,K);

float distance = 0;
for (int q = 0; q < K; q++){
    const Eigen::Vector3f& line = L.col(q);
    const Eigen::Vector3f& point = P.col(q);
    const float d = line.dot(point);
    distance += d*d;
 }
 const float residual2 = distance / K;
```

which outperforms (`g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG`) the fancier reduction techniques, e.g.:

```
 const float residual2 = (L.array() * P.array()).colwise().sum().square().mean();
 const float residual2 = L.cwiseProduct(P).array().colwise().sum().array().square().mean();
 const float residual2 = (L.transpose() * P).diagonal().array().square().mean();
```

Perhaps there is something I am missing here. Shouldn't the reductions be faster?

Edit: Using K = 20.
I perform each of the above 100*632*631 times with the loop version taking about 1200 msec while the others would take around 2000 msec. 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5, MacOS, clang++ -O3

Edit2: Created a [small test program](https://github.com/wcochran/eigentest). Adding `-NDEBUG` for compiling made a *huge* difference (I thought you got this for free with `-O3`). The loop version is *significantly* faster than
the reductions:

```
./eigentest
CASE 1: 12 milliseconds
solution = 1482.5
CASE 2: 835 milliseconds
solution = 1482.5
CASE 3: 849 milliseconds
solution = 1482.5
CASE 4: 843 milliseconds
solution = 1482.5
```

Edit3: I think the test above is crap since the compiler unrolled the loop.... sigh... I'll get back to this soon...

Comment: Define "faster". What kind of difference are we talking about? How long did you benchmark for?

Comment: I would perform each 100 times with the loop version taking about 1200 msec while the others would take around 2000 msec. 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5, MacOS, clang++ -O3.

Comment: That's a measurable difference which is interesting. Thanks for qualifying. Are you sure that these both produce the same output? If so, maybe you've found an optimization that should be incorporated into the library, or the library has suffered a performance regression for some reason.

Comment: Yep. I check the output and its correct in all 4 cases.

Comment: I know generating temporaries is bad, so I tried allocating a matrix or array for the result of the first multiply, but no real improvement.

Comment: Actually the code above is in an inner loop that runs about 600*600 times ... I call that 100 times... I’ll edit this when I get a chance.

Comment: Profile. You have an interesting case, be it for yourself or Eigen developers. You might simply want to profile those different scenarios and see where they spend the most time. If you're using Linux, I cannot recommend `perf record` highly enough.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (including benchmark code)! gcc and clang produce near identical inner loops for your manual loop and the Eigen variants you posted: https://godbolt.org/z/AwkBmW (Eigen peels of the first element, since `.mean()` only makes sense if the size is 1 at least). Leaving out the `-DNDEBUG` should not make much difference (not a 60% difference), since there won't be assertion checks in the inner loop.

Comment: I ran it on my pc, and the second version appears to be faster: 100 ms vs 90ms for your setup (g++ version 7.5, eigen last version from GitHub master branch, -O3). 250ms vs 180 ms for clang 7.0. https://gist.github.com/Solonets/e3da1adadbcfed5383b9945fe1f9f16e

Comment: Created test: https://github.com/wcochran/eigentest  Strange thing is the reductions *are* faster here (1140 ms vs 1589 ms on my machine). The actual codebase I am working has this code deep in an inner loop -- the only difference is the code you see above -- must be something about the context.

Comment: I hope you see the importance of providing a MRE (especially the 'reproducible' part). Your actual code might have a completely independent issue ...

Comment: Added -DNDEBUG and that was a game changer on my small test. The loop version is taking 12 msec, whereas the reductions were taking 830 msecs!!

Comment: @Solon Did you use `-DNDEBUG` as well as `-O3` when compiling? I think you find the loop version much faster.